# Adding strings in array together based on certain scenarios - typescript

Tags: typescript

I am coding in typescript.

I have an array of strings which is then run through a function to alter how they are formatted e.g. a full name is run through a function which will alter how it is set up.

So, I was wondering if there was a way where if I had an array of 4 items, I am trying to connection the first three strings with a comma and the last two with 'and'

An example:

```
str['mike', 'will', 'drake', 'paul']

output: mike, will, drake and paul.
```

Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this in Javascript (I know you're using Typescript)

```
var str = ['mike', 'will', 'drake', 'paul'];
var out = '';
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    if (str.length - 1 > i) {
        out += str[i] + ', ';
    } else if (str.length == i + 1) {
        out = out.slice(0, -2);
        out += ' and ' + str[i];
    }

}
console.log(out);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this was great help! I made the changes to fit my code and data it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the last item in the array, join the remaining ones with a comma, and then add the last name with the 'and'.

So, let's say you have your array:

```
let names = ['mike', 'will', 'drake', 'paul'];
```

To get the last name, you can **pop** the last item:

```
let lastName = names.pop();
```

Now simply **join** the remaining names, and **concatenate** the last one:

```
let result = names.join(',') + ' and ' + lastName;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for a solution, this does work correct. However, only problem is that I use split() to separate the elements so I can make some changes using another function. Therefore they are converted to strings and pop() cannot be used on string type (if that is correct). Much appreciated however!